# JWT signature encoding with private key. Getting Error as "RsaUsingSha alg expects key to be of AsymmetricAlgorithm type."

Tags: docusignapi

I trying to generate signature encoding with private to get access token by JWT grant. I using jwt.net library. I able to get header and body, but getting error when try to generate signature encoding 
    rs256sign(.). I following steps as per docusign site https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken

As per site, we need 3 thing to get access token from docusign API that header, body and signature mentioned in section "Create JWT token". Below is

```
var header = new { alg = "RS256", typ = "JWT" };
var payload1 = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
{"iss", "6cc52d24-cb4f-46de-bf88-d08bf559e8e5"},
{"sub", "fc86d3e0-2d5c-4ebb-9765-cb8b0e011ee4"},
{"iat", 1589979664},
{"exp", 1590008421},
{"aud", "account-d.docusign.com"},
{"scope", "signature impersonation"}
};

byte[] pBytes = 
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload1, 
Formatting.None));
byte[] hBytes = 
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(header, 
Formatting.None));
string stringToSign = Convert.ToBase64String(hBytes) + "." +     
Convert.ToBase64String(pBytes);
string token = Jose.JWT.Encode(stringToSign, privateKey, JwsAlgorithm.RS256);
```

Comment: I highly recommend you use one of the SDKs instead of doing this yourself. You can use Java, javascrtip etc.

Comment: I can't use SDKs as we can't upgrade framework, because our project is live.

Comment: are you using .NET version 4.5?

Comment: Yes, MS Visual Studio 2012 and framework 4.5

Comment: can you use this nuget package/dll ? https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle/ ? this one implements the cryptography needed for JWT. It's not clear to me if it would work with 4.5, I think you should try.

Comment: Thank you Inbar, I already started to work with library. Let us see what will result.

Comment: so what error do you get?

Comment: I done it by using nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle library.

Comment: great, I put this in answer so it can help others. Feel free to mark this question answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by including the [Bouncy Castle nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle/) in your project.
While our SDK requires a higher version of .NET (4.5.2 or above) that dll may be ok with VS 2020 and .NET 4.5

Comment: Here is good link to explain this. Finally I understand the point we want to develop. https://blog.todotnet.com/2018/02/public-private-keys-and-signing/                                                                      Now moving to next step to connect, mean to get details after signing process complete. Developing API to receive message from docusign.